# Is there a way to run script with zx that requires user input in github actions

Tags: github, github-actions, action

We have a script that runs by zx and take user input (which is a token) to generate .env files from the server.

```
#!/usr/bin/env zx

const ENV_LIST = fs
  .readdirSync('apps')
  .filter(dir => !dir.endsWith('e2e') && !dir.startsWith('.'));
const GLOBAL_ENV_DIR = path.join(__dirname, '../../../../.env');
const getAppEnvDir = appName =>
  path.join(__dirname, `../../../../apps/${appName}/.env`);

let token = await question("Submit your team's API token ");

['global', ...ENV_LIST].forEach(env => {
  fetch(
    `[url to fetch]`,
    {
      headers: {
        Accept: 'application/json',
        Authorization: `Basic ${token}`,
      },
      method: 'GET',
    },
  )
    .then(res => res.text())
    .then(res => {
      const { content } = JSON.parse(
        JSON.parse(res).results[0].body.atlas_doc_format.value,
      );

      const filteredEnvList = content.filter(({ type }) =>
        /heading|codeBlock/.test(type),
      );

      const foundDevEnvIndex = filteredEnvList.findIndex(
        item =>
          item.type === 'heading' &&
          item.content[0].text.toLowerCase() === 'development',
      );

      fs.writeFileSync(
        env === 'global' ? GLOBAL_ENV_DIR : getAppEnvDir(env),
        filteredEnvList[foundDevEnvIndex + 1].content[0].text + '\n',
        { encoding: 'utf8' },
      );
    });
});
```

is there a way to run this script via github action and instead of user input, use github secrets ?

Answer (score 0):

You can map secret as env variable and then just replace this line `let token = await question("Submit your team's API token ");` to read it form env variable

```
  - run: |
      # make file runnable, might not be necessary
      chmod +x "${GITHUB_WORKSPACE}/.github/script.sh"

      # run script
      "${GITHUB_WORKSPACE}/.github/script.sh"
    env:
      SECRETS_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.SECRETS_TOEKN }}
```

You may need make your script first runnable by calling `chmod +x` on your script

Comment: can you give me an example executing mjs file? cause the script is written in js